# Calling Winspool API GetJOB issue

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, visual-c++

I am writing a Visual C++ program to get the print job detail information.
The code as the following:

```
HANDLE hPrinter;
DWORD needed, returned, byteUsed,level;
JOB_INFO_2   *pJobStorage1=NULL;
level = 2;

GetJob(hPrinter, jobId, level, NULL, 0, &needed);
if (GetLastError()!=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    cout << "GetJobs failed with error code"
    << GetLastError() << endl;
pJobStorage1 = (JOB_INFO_2 *)malloc(needed);
ZeroMemory(pJobStorage1, needed); 
cout << GetJob(hPrinter, jobId, level, (LPBYTE)pJobStorage1, needed, (LPDWORD)&byteUsed) << endl;
cout << pJobStorage1[0].pPrinterName<<endl;
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/dd144894(v=vs.85).aspx), the output of pJobStorage1 is not an array,however, the IDE report error when I change

```
 pJobStorage1[0].pPrinterName
```

to

```
  pJobStorage1.pPrinterName
```

So, I want to know what is going on.

Comment: It is not an array.  You correctly declared it as a pointer, and did the memory management right (don't forget free(), let's not quibble about new vs malloc), you just need `->` to dereference it.  Hup Holland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pointer. Just see the declaration `JOB_INFO_2   *pJobStorage1=NULL`

With  `pJobStorage1[0].pPrinterName` and  `pJobStorage1->pPrinterName` you access the first element pJobStorage1 ist pointing to.

`pJobStorage1.pPrinterName` is invalid because `pJobStorage1` and you can not derefernce a pointer with the . operator.

If you define an array `JOB_INFO_2 foo[5]`. foo itself is the address/pointer to  the first array element. So you can use foo instead of a `JOB_INFO_2 *`. So if you have an array name you can use it instead of a pointer. Also a pointer defines an address of an element of a specific type. You may use it as an array.

Pointer and arrays have interchangeable usage.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
};

void Foo()
{
    A a[3], *pa;
    pa = a;

    A b;
    // Accessing first element
    b = *a;
    b = a[0];
    b = pa[0];
    b = *pa;

    // Accessing second element
    b = a[1];
    b = pa[1];
    b = *(pa+1);

    // accessing member in first element.
    int c;
    c = a[0].a;
    c = pa[0].a;
    c = pa->a;
    c = (*pa).a;
}
```

Comment: Is it for an object, I can use . operator to access the member only?
For a pointer, I can use -> operator to access the member only?

Comment: No. You can derefernce the pointer and use the . changed my answer, see last line.